How NOT to compile images stored inside TImage?
I want to see pictures inside TImage at design-time on the form, but not to compile them into the exe file, because it increases the exe file significantly. I load these pictures at runtime anyway.
Of course, I can remove images before compilation, but it is not a convenient way. Perhaps, there are compile directives for it?
Any solution?

What you are asking for is not possible with the standard TImage. It always saves its picture to the DFM. You could try deriving a new class from TImage to disable its native DFM streaming behavior. But one side-effect is you will lose your picture every time you load your Form/project. Another option may be to use the Form's OnPaint event to draw a picture onto the Form dynamically, then you can choose one file at design-time and a different file at runtime.

@RemyLebeau Yes, you are right. I derived a new class from TPaintBox, and set new property called FilePath. Here I do the magic with images... So instead of storing whole picture I store only the filepath, which loads image dynamicaly...
